# How can I override CSS dynamically with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

I have bootstrap tabs and I want to assign some css properties to the active tab based on the data received from server (color code for the respective data set). How can I override the css values for the border color using angularjs to the active tab?

Here is the HTML and CSS code:

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
 <!--style for the tabs border -->
   <ul id='myTabs' class="nav nav-tabs" ng-style="{'border-right-color':[currentData.colorCode]}">
   <!-- Active tab -->
      <li ng-class="getTabClass(0)" ng-click="setActiveTab(0)" class="active"><a href="#tab0" data-toggle="tab">Set 1</a></li>
      <li ng-class="getTabClass(1)" ng-click="setActiveTab(1)" ><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Set 2</a></li>
      <li ng-class="getTabClass(0)" ng-click="setActiveTab(2)"><a href="#tab0" data-toggle="tab">Set 3</a></li>
      <li ng-class="getTabClass(1)" ng-click="setActiveTab(3)" ><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Set 4</a></li>
   </ul>
```

CSS Code:

```
.tabs-left>.nav-tabs .active>a, .tabs-left>.nav-tabs .active>a:hover, .tabs-left>.nav-tabs .active>a:focus {
border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
color: #555;
cursor: default;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs>.active>a, .nav-tabs>.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>.active>a:focus {
color: #555555;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your controller function getTabClass(#)

Comment: Just load the CSS into the page after the bootstrap CSS and yours would take priority, as long as your rules are at least as specific as the rules in the bootstrap CSS. Or is the CSS you are attempting to add dynamic?

Comment: @SoEzPz, Here is my getTabClass(#) function:

    $scope.getTabClass = function (tabNum) {
      return tabClasses[tabNum];
        $scope.style = function(value) {
          return { "background-color": value };
      }
    };

Comment: @Enzey, I want to load dynamic CSS properties through angularjs. The values will be returned from the server. I hope it clarifies the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, you would like to change the CSS for the active li element?  Or the ul border color based on which li is active?

Comment: @SoEzPz, I would like to change the CSS for the active li element.

Comment: I am just wondering what you are using getTabClass for?  You have (0) then (1) and so on, is this to just alternate color for each tab? Like if you wanted the rows to be different color?

Comment: I am using getTabClass to get the tab and to show different data based on the tab number.

Comment: OK, let's play around with this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/pusqrowu/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ng-style="{'border-right-color':[currentData.colorCode]}">
```

to

```
ng-style="{'border-right-color':'{{currentData.colorCode}}'}">
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/aykw1ufe/

Comment: <ng-style="{'border-right-color':[currentData.colorCode]}">

The above code is working perfectly fine with the tabs border. I want to set the border color for the active tab.